# NPP function returns nppiFilterRow_8u_C1R CUDA KERNEL execution error

Tags: nsight, npp

I am using nvidia nsight application to rotate and blur images. I am using the NPP libraries for the same,
The oDeviceDst gets filled the data from the output of function rotate, which is working fine.The code is shown below: **Also note that the below piece of code is in a for loop for some rotation angles**.

```
npp::ImageNPP_8u_C1 oDeviceDst(768 , 768);

Npp32s masksize = (Npp32s)KERNEL_LENGTH; 

Npp32s anchor = (Npp32s)KERNEL_RADIUS;

NppiSize SzROI ={(int)oDeviceDst_gauss.width(),(int)oDeviceDst_gauss.height()};

std::cout << " anchor " << anchor << std::endl; std::cout << " masksize " << masksize << std::endl;

NppStatus status2 = nppiFilterRow_8u_C1R(oDeviceDst.data(), oDeviceDst.pitch(), oDeviceDst_gauss.data(), oDeviceDst_gauss.pitch(), SzROI, (Npp32s*)h_Kernel, masksize , anchor, int(sumh));

std::cerr << "status of blur is" << status2 << std::endl;
```

But as soon as i run it(remote on target), I get a status of -1000.
status of blur is -1000.

logout

Has anyone faced a similar issue in usage of NPP libraries.

Comment: Based on https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/e6ce58fef4b11d745f1795af0d79a326904ad1e5/Common/UtilNPP/ImageAllocatorsNPP.h#L74, it appears allocation failed. Check if previous memory allocations are being freed, or if it is too big an image ?

Comment: Thanks Prabindh, although a different error now:   NPP_CUDA_KERNEL_EXECUTION_ERROR = -1000

Comment: Got it, there was a issue in one of the parameters of nppiRowfilter. The kernel values were assigned from host and it should be a device variable. There is no image allocator error now. Although, the kernel execution error persists. Thanks Prabindh!